# How do i subtract ticks from another tick

Tags: c#, datetime

This is what i got:

Get timing handle for `loginstart` from session

```
var markStored = PPSession.TimingMarks["loginstart"];
```

get ticks from `utcnow`

```
var markNow = PPSession.TimingMarks["loginstart"] 
    = new TimingMark { endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks };
```

And want to Subtract current from stored ticks

```
diff = markStored - markNow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your last line:

1. First of all `markNow` is a `TimingMark` so unless you have overridden the `-` operator you should specify what property in it is the one you want to use to do the `-` operation (otherwise it is like saying `object - object`)
2. Same as the above - also for your `markStored` you should specify the propery of the time, on which you want to do `-`

So:

```
var diff = markStored.timeField.Ticks - markNow.endTime;
```

And with stub data:

```
var markStored = new { Time = DateTime.Now };
var markNow = new { endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks };
var diff = markStored.Time.Ticks - markNow.endTime;
```

Comment: getting "'TimingMark' does not contain a definition for 'addTicks' acceipting a first argument of type 'TimingMark' could be found"

Comment: Did you add the `.Ticks`?

Comment: @Callum - Cool :) glad to hear